# Prevent Bootstrap columns overlapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Could you lease tell me how to prevent the brands select box from being hidden behind the date. I gave minimum width to dates because I do not want them to collapse more than the minimum width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-12 row widget-simple remove-padding-top margin-bottom-10">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group credits-daterange">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 control-label vertical-center" for="start_date">Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="input-group input-daterange" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" style="min-width: 236px;">
                            <input class="form-control text-center" id="start_date" name="start_date" placeholder="From" required="required" type="text" value="2013-08-01"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>

                            <input class="form-control text-center" id="end_date" name="end_date" placeholder="To" required="required" type="text" value="2015-08-03">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
                        <option value="0">All Brands</option>
                        <option value="9618">Brand 1</option>
                        <option value="10268">Brand 2</option>
                        <option value="10232">Brand 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
                        <option value="Created">status 1</option>
                        <option value="Downloaded">Status 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 pull-right">
                <input class="hidden" id="search_txt" name="search_txt" type="text" value="">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" id="agencies-export-excel" name="commit" type="submit" value="Export to Excel">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/y97gpyyh/)**

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: When I run your code the brands select box is visible. Can you elaborate on how you want it to appear?

Comment: I don't see the overlap you describe in the demo I added to your question. I do see, however, that you're nesting column elements without the required row element in between. You also have top-level columns without a row around them. Resolving that may help.

Comment: Remove "style="min-width: 236px;", else in small view it breaks the bootstrap % strategy

Comment: @Zee,isherwood: maybe the overlapp is not the right term when i reduce the width of chrome browser a portion of select box gets hidden behind the date

Answer (score 4):

The overlap is due to `style="min-width: 236px;`

If you remove it, you can this that the issue is gone away.

---

Here is a fiddle : http://www.bootply.com/KFgIJ6z5ld

---

Your code without your custom style :

```
<div class="col-md-12 row widget-simple remove-padding-top margin-bottom-10">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group credits-daterange">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 control-label vertical-center" for="start_date">Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="input-group input-daterange" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                            <input class="form-control text-center" id="start_date" name="start_date" placeholder="From" required="required" type="text" value="2013-08-01"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>

                            <input class="form-control text-center" id="end_date" name="end_date" placeholder="To" required="required" type="text" value="2015-08-03">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
                        <option value="0">All Brands</option>
                        <option value="9618">Brand 1</option>
                        <option value="10268">Brand 2</option>
                        <option value="10232">Brand 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
                        <option value="Created">status 1</option>
                        <option value="Downloaded">Status 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 pull-right">
                <input class="hidden" id="search_txt" name="search_txt" type="text" value="">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" id="agencies-export-excel" name="commit" type="submit" value="Export to Excel">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

One other way is to make bigger your cells :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/KzRD6fb0Pw

**Code** :

```
<div class="col-md-12 row widget-simple remove-padding-top margin-bottom-10">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group credits-daterange">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 control-label vertical-center" for="start_date">Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="input-group input-daterange" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                            <input class="form-control text-center" id="start_date" name="start_date" placeholder="From" required="required" type="text" value="2013-08-01"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>

                            <input class="form-control text-center" id="end_date" name="end_date" placeholder="To" required="required" type="text" value="2015-08-03">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
                        <option value="0">All Brands</option>
                        <option value="9618">Brand 1</option>
                        <option value="10268">Brand 2</option>
                        <option value="10232">Brand 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
                        <option value="Created">status 1</option>
                        <option value="Downloaded">Status 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 pull-right">
                <input class="hidden" id="search_txt" name="search_txt" type="text" value="">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" id="agencies-export-excel" name="commit" type="submit" value="Export to Excel">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand. Is there any other alternative to make the date fields  always show full date. Because at some level i cannot see the full date when the browser width is reduced.

Comment: @KarimMtl with [this](http://www.bootply.com/fvrg7hStZs) it seems to be always visible

Comment: i thought form-group is equivalent to row. I will add rows below the form controls and see how it looks like. Thanks

Comment: you are right it is looking better now do i still need to implement the row you mentioned earlier?